# Access data of child template class of parent class

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

struct A { void what_type() { cout<<"A"<<endl; }};
struct B { void what_type() { cout<<"B"<<endl; }};

class MyCommonAncestor {

}; 

template <class T> 
class MyTemplateClass : public MyCommonAncestor {

   public:  
       std::unordered_map<int, T> myx; 
};

int main() {
    vector<shared_ptr<MyCommonAncestor>> myVector; 
    myVector.push_back(make_shared<MyTemplateClass<A>>()); 
    myVector.push_back(make_shared<MyTemplateClass<B>>()); 

   for (auto& x: myVector)
       x->myx; // just for the shake of this example
 return 0;
}
```

How can I find a way to actually access the `myx` member variable from `MyTemplateClass` maintaining the use of template because I need it.

I receive the following error:

```
error: ‘class MyCommonAncestor’ has no member named ‘myx’
```

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically cast the pointer to your template class. But the point of inheritance to put commonality into your base class otherwise what's the point of their existence.

Comment: "...of inheritance *is* to put... " ?

Comment: I think the word you are looking for is *polymorphism*.  The point the inheritance is polymorphism.  The OP's code example violates Liskov's Substitution Principle, by wanting to downcast.  Demonstrates a bad design smell.

Comment: I actually tried something like this but I can't use it because the template class, well, needs its T.  ((*MyTemplateClass )x)->myx; It tells me that the template argument is missing and that's normal, but now I can't pass the template argument. This makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

Try to place this member (an abstraction of it, independent of T) and its access to your base class if possible. In doubt it depends on what exactly you want to achieve with this access. For a lot of problem classes of this type, the actual type T is not really necessary at all for the public access. If that's not possible, take a look at the coercion by member template scheme! The base principles of this pattern might be useful for some special problems of this category.

Keep in mind, that templates and polymorphism are (quite) orthogonal aspects in C++.

Comment: The whole idea is to have a template class that has an unordered map ( for the map I need the template ) and then to store this class in a vector. Then loop and get all the classes with all their unordered maps, for this I am aming. I need this base class to use it as a pointer so that I can get pass the template class and actually use the data from the template class if this makes sense. The T is "dynamic", in the sense that I have a bunch of structs that I want to use them for the maps, it's not predefined so this forces me to find a way around the template class to get its data

Comment: Yes I understood this but what do you want to achieve after this? That's the important question. Nevertheless, your map has some kind of interface character. For many cases, that's not a good design approach. I think, the key approach to your actual issue lies in a smart abstraction of this map.

Comment: My plan is to build a simple Entity-Component-System, this vector is going to store all the maps with their particular components, one map is let's say for positions, another for velocities. This is why I need the template. Every map has its own "Type", one for position structs, another for velocitie etc. Maybe I have to think of another solution just like you say. The problem is that I am beginner and I am learning on the go.

Comment: Believe me, for almost all these scenarios, a simple abstraction of this member is the way to go. Create an interface IMyMapType or if you really want this map as a fixed container IMyMapValueType only for its values and define your interface in terms of what you really want to achieve. A second very strong approach is the variant/visitor scheme here, really powerful and fast for several problem categories but with several drawbacks especially for cases where you don't really know what the final usage lines are.